# Google Drive indigestion over folder I moved from one place to another

Tags: google-drive, synchronization

I have Google's Backup and Sync (current incarnation of Google Drive for PC) installed on two laptops.

In the web interface, on Chrome, I dragged the folder "Tools" to the folder "Automation."  On both of my laptops, this change does not show up in Windows Explorer.

Inspection of the blue arrow in the white cloud symbol in the Task Tray reveals "Can't sync one item" --> Download Error - ...\Tools".

Both laptops are running Windows 7.  The folder Tools is within the file hierarchy owned by my work persona, which uses the Google Suite, and as a result when I shared the main folder, there was a warning message that the folder was going to be shared with someone outside the organization.  Does that have something to do with the problem?  Is it because of the way I moved the folder?

I tried quitting Backup and Sync on one laptop and then restarting the sync program -- that didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

Turns out there was a file within the Tools subfolder that was open on one of the laptops.

It's a shame the browser interface didn't detect that -- but I suppose that would be asking too much.

Comment: How do you expect chrome to get list of open file handles? Is that safe? Security issues are not a problem? I guess they can think of some logic, but when its OS info you want to retrieve, you should not guess, either you can get the data or not.

Comment: @ilansch - you mean I can't expect my computer to read my mind?  What I mean to say is, I'm glad I found the solution to my problem, and I plan to watch out for this in future.